# How to slow down Framer animations

Tags: animation, css-animations, framerjs

I'm looking for a solution to slow down FramerJS animations by a certain amplitude.

In the [Velocity Animation framework](http://velocityjs.org) it's posible to do `Velocity.mock = 10`, to slow down everything by a factor of `10`.

Either the docs are lacking in the respect, or this feature doesn't currently exist and should *really* be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Framer.Loop.delta = 1 / 120
```

to slow down all the animations by a factor of 2. The default value is [1 / 60](https://github.com/koenbok/Framer/blob/master/framer/AnimationLoop.coffee#L26).

Comment: Just wanna add that it doesn't affect any Utils.delay calls that you may have in your code, affects animations ONLY

Answer (score 1):

While Javier's answer works for most animations, it doesn't apply to delays. While not ideal, the method I've adopted is to set up a debugging variable and function, and pass every time-related value through it:

```coffee
slowdown = 5
s = (ms) ->
  return ms * slowdown
```

Then use it like so:

```coffee
Framer.Defaults.Animation =
  time: s 0.3
```

…and:

```coffee
Utils.delay s(0.3), ->
  myLayer.sendToBack()
```

Setting the `slowdown` variable to `1` will use your standard timing (anything times 1 is itself).